# Error with OPENQUERY

Tags: sql, openquery

I have this proble. 
I should to call a Function at a LinkedServer database. So this database not show me a Function.

For this I use this code:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000)
    DECLARE @Data as DATE
    SET @Data = GETDATE()

    SET  @TSQL = 'SELECT PIPPO FROM OPENQUERY([SQLIMELTC\IMELTCPROD],''SELECT  [FlexNet].[dbo].[AF_GetUTCToLocal] (''''' +CAST(@Data AS NVARCHAR(100))+ ''''') AS PIPPO'' )'
    EXEC @TSQL
END
```

I have this error:

```
Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 10
The name 'SELECT PIPPO FROM OPENQUERY([SQLIMELTC\IMELTCPROD],'SELECT  [FlexNet].[dbo].[AF_GetUTCToLocal] (''2015-01-08'') AS PIPPO' )' is not a valid identifier.
```

But, if I try to use this code before the instruction

```
EXEC @TSQL
```

and use it:

```
SELECT @TSQL
```

And after the execute I select in output box the result and execute it, it works.
What is my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) syntax. When you use the variable you should use it in brackets.
Try this:

```
EXEC (@TSQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put parenthesis around `@TSQL`, e.g.

```
EXEC (@TSQL);
```

`EXEC` without parenthesis is for executing stored procedures. e.g.

```
DECLARE @TSQL VARCHAR(8000) = 'sp_lock';
EXEC @TSQL;
```

Will execute the stored procedure `sp_lock`

Better still [use `sp_executesql`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql), thus avoiding ambiguity:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @TSQL;
```